# Non monotonic feature selection decision

Tags: machine-learning, artificial-intelligence, feature-selection

Why is it bad to have a non monotonic feature when attempting to determine an output. For example why would it be bad to select a temperature for determining a patients health?

Answer (score 0):

In opposit I say.

Suppose we consider two features F1(time),F2(temprature) that F2 varies monotically with F1.

Simple answer:

- Entropy of F2 given F1 is low.
- Correlation of F1 and F2 is too high.

Don't worry cause the first feature selection algorithm removes it! :)